# How can I tell Windows to Ignore a USB device?

Tags: windows, usb, phone

I plug my phone into USB just so it can charge up. I don't want to see a dialog box (the Found New Hardware Wizard) each time looking for the device drivers. I never intend to use the phone with this computer -- just charge the phone.

I would prefer to ignore only that specific device, if possible. Thanks.

Maybe there is a dummy, do-nothing driver somewhere.

Comment: I also tried plugging the phone into a second monitor, which has no USB connection to the computer. For my Dell monitor, anyway, it didn't charge the phone in that configuration.

Comment: maybe for some reason there's no power coming out the USB on the monitor.. if you have a ps2 keyboard and a usb-ps2 adaptor and you plug it in then the lights should flash, if there's power out of there. otherwise not sure how to check

Comment: dell monitor aside,  a)the phone might or will charge faster in the mains since more current is available b)if you let it install the driver first time then maybe likely that nothing will pop up after. It'd be interesting if what you speak of exists though. And I suppose you don't want to turn off your phone.  Current answers are better, but as a crazy theoretical idea, you could hack a USB cable and snip the data wires. I think it's 4 wires 2 data the other 2 you keep - 5V and GND. I did something like that before for some reason.

Comment: You could always buy a 'power/charge only' USB lead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try going into the Device Manager and setting the device to disabled.

Comment: This worked perfectly. The phone showed up as "USB Composite Device" in the USB tree in Device Manager.

Comment: If you want something to use via command line the `devcon` command will let you do most of the things `devmgmt.msc` lets you do, in addition to simulating device disconnection.

Answer (score 0):

Is your phone a droid by any chance?  There is a setting on the droids for 'charge only'.  If you reply with your phone model, I can try and find a quick answer. My point is, I think its in different places on each phone.

Comment: Yes,it is an HTC Droid Eris, but the question was about the Windows side. My phone is already set to "Charge Only".